# How to run GitHub Actions workflow only if the pushed changes are in a specific *line* of a specific file?

Tags: clojure, yaml, github-actions, workflow, continuous-deployment

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Now, I am trying to make dependencies become private Maven packages hosted for free on GitHub packages. I already managed to publish some package!

Right now, I have on my `.yml` file:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'project.clj'
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'project.clj'
```

*If my understanding is correct*, this means that the GitHub workflows only runs after Pull Requests on tweaking file `project.clj` and direct changes on `main branch` tweaking `project.clj`.

This is **close** to what I need!

**Context**: I am building this to publish Maven packages as GitHub packages. As clojure folks might know, usually, the version of the project is "hard code-documented" on the **first line** of `project.clj` file. Hence, *I want to publish a new package every time this library gets a new version*.

For instance, the first line has:

```clj
(defproject my-repository "0.6.50-RELEASE-TEST-9-via-GitHub-Actions-CD"
```

At some point, it will be changed to:

```clj
(defproject my-repository "0.6.51"
```

I would like to adjust the GitHub Actions script so that it only runs for changes on this file `project.clj` **and** on the first line!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try really hard enough, you can pull it off, but there's a simpler way:

You can read contents of a file and set that as a version of your library:

```clj
(defproject foobar (clojure.string/trim (slurp "./VERSION"))
```

then in your workflow, you don't watch for changes to `project.clj` but the `VERSION` file only, that you can update using a script or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a bash command to check if first line of certain file changed:

```bash
jobs:
  first-line-filter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    # run only if 'project.clj' file is changed and commit hash of current commit is same as commit of change
    - name: second step
      if: git blame project.clj -L 1,2 | awk '{print $1;}' == git rev-parse --short HEAD
      run: echo "Running"
```

I type this from a phone so not sure about actual syntax, but I think idea of comparing current hash with hash of git blame of first line should work. There are out of the box path filter steps which you can use if a certain file changed, but not the line AFAIK, that you can use for earlier filtering maybe.